# ASP.NET MVC - How can I check if a file exists on an ftp server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ftp

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5.1 web site, and I need to show a picture if it exists in an ftp server (CDN). Foldername and filename are tied to rules so I know them beforehand. I need to display a message if this file does not exist.

How can I check if this file exists?

[Suggested duplicate (Verify if file exists or not in C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415962/verify-if-file-exists-or-not-in-c-sharp) does not help since I need to check if the file exists on a *remote* server and not a *local* folder.

Comment: This is your sample problem : [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347897/how-to-check-if-file-exists-on-ftp-before-ftpwebrequest)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
  string destination = "ftp://something.com/";
    string file = "test.jpg";
    string extention = Path.GetExtension(file);
    string fileName = file.Remove(file.Length - extention.Length);
    string fileNameCopy = fileName;
    int attempt = 1;

    while (!CheckFileExists(GetRequest(destination + "//" + fileNameCopy + extention)))
    {
        fileNameCopy = fileName + " (" + attempt.ToString() + ")";
        attempt++;
    }

    // do your upload, we've got a name that's OK
}

private static FtpWebRequest GetRequest(string uriString)
{
    var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uriString);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;

    return request;
}

private static bool checkFileExists(WebRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        request.GetResponse();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Reference from [FTP Check if file exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313693/ftp-check-if-file-exist-when-uploading-and-if-it-does-rename-it-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks, I'll also use this in case I need to upload the file as well.